# How to change MAC address

Tags: windows-7, mac-address, mobile-broadband

I have lenovo laptop with integrated Ericsson H5321 Mobile Broadband device. I need to change its MAC address but it seems there is no program which could do that (Technitium TMAC, Lizard Systems Change Mac Address, SMAC). I also tried to change corresponding OriginalNetworkAddress and NetworkAddress values in windows regedit. Nothing helped me to change it.

Comment: Did you try this [link](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-change-mac-address/)

Comment: I don't have this laptop with me just right now but I will try later. Dont think it will work cause I tried more advanced "windows registry" way.

Comment: "Mobile Broadband"? Is that Wi-Fi or something else?

Comment: I think it is 3G modem

Answer (score 0):

I use [SMAC Pro](http://www.klcconsulting.net/smac/) to accomplish this, and this works on my NIC.

It might be that you can't change it with the trial version ?

Comment: No doubt of it in case if your NIC is Ethernet card or Wi-Fi adapter. What about device similar to mine? It is internal usb 3G modem.

Comment: Have you tried it using the Pro version? In all cases the hardware MAC remains unchangeable, only some software MAC spoof is implemented at Windows register level.